# iOS 8: Cannot change the navigation bar at all of the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

Tags: ios, abpeoplepickerview

I try to change the color of the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController navbar to my app colors. However no changes occur. Even when I try to hide it or at least change the status bar tint color, nothing happens. Why?

```
- (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
{
    if(!_peoplePicker){
        _peoplePicker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc]init];
        _peoplePicker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
        _peoplePicker.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    }
    return _peoplePicker;
}
```

I lazy instantiate my navigation controller and the other method calls like dismiss view controller etc. work fine.

**EDIT: This is my current code (for the bounty)**. No color changes happen like this:

```
- (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
{
    if(!_peoplePicker){
        _peoplePicker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc]init];
        _peoplePicker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
        _peoplePicker.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    return _peoplePicker;
}

- (IBAction)addressBookButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    [self presentViewController:self.peoplePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Doesn't this work anymore on iOS8?

Comment: Where's your attempt to change the colors?

Comment: Just showed an example with the hidden property that nothing works, not even hidden. Or navigationBar.tint neither..

Comment: In my own app, simply setting the app navbar colors through the standard appearance proxy results in the navbar of `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` appearing in the same app colors. Nothing special was needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, thanks to the comment above, I realized that an appearance proxy should work like so:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Just put that in the viewDidLoad method of the View Controller from which you are instigating the ABPeoplePickerView. This will also work for MFMailerView as well.
My code that I'm using to style my bars properly is:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont
                                                                       fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:12], NSFontAttributeName,
                            [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class], nil] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [picker.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

I call these methods before presenting the person picker not even in the viewdidload.

Answer (score 1):

the color issue: The navigationBar might not be loaded at the point when you are trying to access it. Have you tried to set the color properties after presenting the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController.

the hide issue: Normally you hide the NavigationBar by calling:

```
- (void)setNavigationBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

on UINavigationController, in your case ABPeoplePickerNavigationController.

Cheers, Fabian

Answer (score 1):

You are using an instance variable (iVar) `_peoplePicker`, which belongs apparently to a property `peoplePicker`. Additionally, you have a method `peoplePicker` that returns an object of class `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *`.
In your `IBAction` `addressBookButtonClicked:` you execute the instruction

```
[self presentViewController:self.peoplePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This means you call your method `peoplePicker`, which checks the iVar `_peoplePicker` and sets it (e.g. the tint color) if it has a `nil` value.
But since you are using the iVar directly, i.e. `_peoplePicker` instead of `self.peoplePicker`, you do not use the setter method, but simply an assignment.
This means the retain count of the `UIColor` object that you create in `[UIColor blackColor]` with an retain count of 1 will not be increased by the instruction `_peoplePicker.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];` but will be put into an autorelease pool when it is returned by `return _peoplePicker;`. But the autoreleasepool will be drained when you app returns to the main event loop, and the `UIColor` object will be released.
So I suggest that you replace all assignments to `_peoplePicker` by assignments to `self.peoplePicker`. Then you are using the setter method, which will increase the retain count, and your `UIColor` object will survive.

Comment: I've tried this but didn't work. Wouldn't make sense in my opinion anyway? Because my getter returns the iVar so the color should still be asigned shouldn't it?